# change databound in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to change color / backcolor in gridview asp.net by databoud, i try like this i have found error. what there is solution with this problem. thanks

Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

```
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            If (e.Row.Cells(1).Text) = "102" Then
                e.Row.Cells(1).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What error did you find?

Comment: You need to change `Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound` to `Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "12")
          {
              e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
          }
else if(e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "13")
          {
              e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
          }
```

Comment: Hi Amir, try add comments to your answer to describe your solution, it's really easier for the OP and anyone looking for a solution to similar problem